# Block matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
\begin{align}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & a I_n \\
b I_n & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.  I want to prove whether this $A$ can be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ by computing characteristic polynomials and minimal polynomials.

$|A - \lambda I| = \left|\begin{pmatrix}
 -\lambda I_n & a I_n \\
b I_n & -\lambda I_n
\end{pmatrix} \right| = |\lambda I_n | | -\lambda I_n + a b \lambda I_n| =  |- \lambda I_n| | \left( - \lambda + \frac{ab}{\lambda}\right) I_n | = (\lambda^2 - ab)^n $

Here I used, for invertible matrix $A,B,C,D$,

\begin{align}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    A & B \\
    C & D
  \end{vmatrix} = |A| | D - CA^{-1} B|  
\end{align}

So characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda^2 - ab)^n$. Apparently, $A^2 = ab \begin{pmatrix} 
I_n & 0 \\
0 & I_n
\end{pmatrix}$ so minimal polynomial is $\lambda^2 - ab$.

Now I want to determine whether this is diagonalizable or not.  I am stuck with this. What is a good approach for showing this be diagonalizable or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is diagonalizable over some field $K$ if and only if its minimal polynomial is split with simple roots over $K$.

As you have correctly computed, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $X^2 - ab$. This polynomial has degree $2$, so it is easy to discuss its behaviour over $\mathbb R$.

It splits over $\mathbb R$ if and only if $ab\geq 0$. It splits over $\mathbb R$ with simple roots if and only if $ab>0$.

With this, you know precisely when the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$, depending on the choices of the coefficients $a,b\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is not always diagonalizable. Take $n=1, a=0, b=1$ to obtain $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ which is not diagonalizable.

Therefore, you can not prove the general diagonalizability of your matrix.